# remote logcat - Android Studio

Tags: android, logcat

Is it possible to see the logcat of an app that is on a distant device, in short, is it possible to logcat remotely?

I sent an app to a client, this is giving error in your device, I tested with the emulator in the same version, but the error only occurred with it.

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

Comment: I think it is theoretically possible. You can try run the adb with tcp then connect to your client networking using vpn. Though I never test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to see the logcat of an app that is on a distant
>   device, in short, is it possible to logcat remotely?

It is possible to connect device over wifi to perform debugging. You can refer to this [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless). However, it has limitation that both the device and the host needs to be connected to common wifi.

Since your device is in customer premises and cannot be under common wifi, there is no other way to perform remote debugging.

### **Alternatives:**

**1. For logical Errors**

The best alternative would be to store logs in local directory (Internal storage or SdCard) and ask  your customer to send these logs. You can use libraries like [logback-android](https://libraries.io/maven/com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic) which facilitates this functionality at ease. You just need to perform some configuration.

**2. For crash**

You can integrate some crash analytics like Hockey app which will notify the crash along with the related stacktrace. If you want detailed information about pre-condition then you have to go for Alternative 1.