# How to find the reason my app stopped without Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just finished my last app and after intensive testing on android studio no bugs or errors pooped up.

But when I use my phone for some time and try to check my app it crashes, and error pops up.

Is there a way to find out the stack trace od that error? specially since its not connected to my PC.

Comment: I'm gonna use "pooped up" from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate tools for analyse, like:

[Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/?authuser=0)

So you have a dashboard and can setting a e-mail for warning.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use different options:

1. Store logcat file in Internal memory as txt file. This will be best solution since it will provide all the necessary information of pre-conditons for the crash
2. Implement crashanalytics like Hockeyapp
3. Use remote debugging. Refer this [official document](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging) for more info

You can find more details for approach 1 & 2 at: [remote logcat - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206889/remote-logcat-android-studio/50206972#50206972)